# Adding sound in unity without using button

Tags: unity-game-engine

we have a game project in unity. We need add a sound in it. But we need do it without using button (it’s a school work). How can we do this please help us.

Comment: Please provide more context and explain in detail what you are trying to achieve, this is too broad and vague.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The [Unity tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/audio) covers this kind of question.

Comment: The game about math, there is questions and answers. We try to add a audio when users select right answer. We watch unity tutorials and cant generate again. When we add a method of audio in the if blocks it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an audiosource with the proper sound to a GameObject. On your logic script add a reference to that audiosource and when the user responds with the correct answer use audiosource.Play(). It will look something like this:

```
public Audiosource correctAnswerSound;

void Update(){
     if(userinput == correctAnswer){
         correctAnswerSound.Play();
     }
}
```